# The content is not in the middle of the muiBadge (google Chrome)

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui

I use a MuiBadge (Material UI), it looks good in Firefox, but in Chrome the content (number 3 in the picture) goes down a little bit. I have not applied any css to it yet.

```
 <Badge
          badgeContent={quantity}
          color='primary'
        >
          <ReactSVG
              svgClassName='menu-icon'
              src='/images/cart.svg'
              alt='My cart'
          />
        </Badge>
```

Do you know why and how to fix it?

( the first pic is in firefox, the second one is when opens with Chrome)

[image: in Firefox]

[image: in Chrome]

Comment: classes={{ badge: classes.badge }} you have some css here

Comment: sorry, I forgot to remove it. Actually it defines only the color of the content